# rails_admin params[:query] in select field is ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, globalize

Can't figure out how to filter nested association belongs to while search in rails admin.

I have the following code in my rails_admin config in model.

```
class Painting < ApplicationRecord
...
rails_admin do
  configure :translations, :globalize_tabs

  create do
    field :author do
      searchable [:last_name]
      queryable [:last_name]
      filterable true
    end

    field :genre
    field :technique
    field :material
    field :active
    field :painting_images
    field :author_preview
    field :translations
  end
end
```

[image: rails_admin_filter_search]

I tried every configuration in model. But nothing works. Whatever I enter in this dropdown input is being ignored.

I have the following logs in puma server.

```
 Started GET "/admin/author?associated_collection=author&compact=true&current_action=create&source_abstract_model=painting&query=George" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-14 22:07:11 +0300
Processing by RailsAdmin::MainController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"associated_collection"=>"author", "compact"=>"true", "current_action"=>"create", "source_abstract_model"=>"painting", "query"=>"George", "model_name"=>"author"}
  Admin Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "admins".* FROM "admins" WHERE "admins"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "admins"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Painting Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "paintings".* FROM "paintings" WHERE "paintings"."id" IS NULL ORDER BY "paintings"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "authors"
  Author Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "authors".* FROM "authors" ORDER BY authors.id desc LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 30]]
  Author::Translation Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "author_translations".* FROM "author_translations" WHERE "author_translations"."author_id" IN (114, 113, 112, 111, 110, 109, 108, 107, 106, 105, 104, 103, 102, 101, 100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85)
Completed 200 OK in 61ms (Views: 1.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
```

The thing is everything I enter in input is being processed in parameters but never gets evaluated. So it just ignored, it doesn't filter associated collection by `params[:query]`

I use `globalize` gem for translations and don't know how to properly configure rails admin to use it filters.

I did searching in original repo. 
I think somehow is wrong [this](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/app/controllers/rails_admin/main_controller.rb#L128)

```
def get_collection(model_config, scope, pagination)
  ...
  options = options.merge(query: params[:query]) if params[:query].present?
  ...
  model_config.abstract_model.all(options, scope)
end
```

This query is available here, but it's ignored there.
I tried to use 
   `model_config.abstract_model.all(options, scope).where(last_name: params[:query])`
And this is working. But this is definitely wrong. Can someone help me with more generic approach to this problem?

Comment: Is the author's last_name displayed in the dropdown? If no, you need to redefine `author_name` method for RailsAdmin

Comment: I found an ugly hack to resolve this. If someone will meet this problem, I can help with **not** very well solution.

Answer (score 1):

Rails admin will search associations by using the search defined for that model. 
Meaning you can't define the search on the Painting model but you need to do it on the Author model.

So any search that works when listing Authors will work on that dropdown.
Another thing you need to be aware is that rails admins will ask by default object.title or object.name to display that name. 
You can define those as methods on your Author model.
If you want another method you can configure what rails admin use on config/initializers/rails_admin.rb

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.label_methods = [:rails_admin_title, :name]
end
```

Comment: this didn't work.
`object_label_method { :last_name }` in my `author.rb`
And in list they are shown like Smith, 
see screenshot here
http://take.ms/wFHs4

Comment: Try defining title method on your author.rb model

Comment: `def title  last_name end` didn't do the trick. :(
it still only params[:query] but ignores when comes to sql statement.

Comment: Did you try to define the list block on the Author model? get the search of Author working on the Author list by defining the fields there and you'll solve your dropdown search.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with `rails_admin` and `globalize` gems. I fixed the issue by defining a custom search for a model. For example

```
config.model 'Author' do
  list do
    search_by :search_by_name
    field :id
    field :name
  end
end
```

and inside `Author` model, define `search_by_name` scope and it will fix both searching in Author list page and dropdown in other pages.

```
scope :search_by_name, -> (term) {
    if term.present?
      with_translations.where('author_translations.name like ?', FormatString.new(term, :sql_match).to_s)
    else
      where({})
    end
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Custom-Search